# hsqldb PreparedStatement parameters types

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I faced some unexpected error in expression result:

```
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.syntax_ora=true", null);
  stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select ? * ? * ? from dual");
  stmt.setObject(1, 1000000.00);
  stmt.setObject(2, 0.01);
  stmt.setObject(3, 3.45); // setDouble no difference
  rs = stmt.executeQuery();
  rs.next();
  System.out.println(rs.getObject(1));
```

You can try it, result is 0!
Why? Because hsqldb driver set default parameter type to int.
0.01 converted to 0 in JDBCPreparedStatement.java: 4257
  o = outType.convertToDefaultType(session, o);

How to change parameter type before/after prepareStatement in jdbc? reflect?

Update: So, I create defineParameterType in JDBCPreparedStatement like in [OraclePreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html#defineParameterType_int__int__int_)

```
public void defineParameterType(int index, int type)
{
  if(index <= 0 || index > parameterTypes.length)
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

  Type newType = Type.getDefaultTypeWithSize(type);

  if(newType != null)
    parameterTypes[index - 1] = newType;
}
```

But, it still return 0! Need to change result type also or reparse query. Dig further...

Comment: Why are you using `setObject()` which is subject to auto-boxing and not the more approriate `setBigDecimal()` or `setDouble()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A valid question, but interestingly enough both `setBigDecimal()` and `setDouble()` produce the same result.

Comment: Some databases don't support parameters like this, or the default might be a datatype you don't want. Try adding an explicit cast, or use the `setObject` that takes a type parameter.

Comment: Mark, "select CAST(? AS DOUBLE) * CAST(? AS DOUBLE) * CAST(? AS DOUBLE) from dual" working as it should.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I found without source hack is

```
select CAST(? AS DOUBLE) * CAST(? AS DOUBLE) * CAST(? AS DOUBLE) from dual
```